# API File Download Maximum FIle Size

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, limits

We need to download pdf documents from external server that supports REST and SOAP. What is the maximum file size that I can download via the GET call request? I see that maximum payload size of Response for Sync API calls is 6 MB. So does that mean I will not be able to download documents that are greater than 6 MB?

Comment: You can use HttpResponse method `getBodyAsBlob` to fetch the response as a file. In Async mode this has a limit of `12 MB`.
What is your file size?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpResponse method `getBodyAsBlob` to fetch the response as a file. In Async mode this has a limit of `12 MB`.

Also if your file size is more than 12MB then making such calls from Apex wont be feasible as you will hit heap size issues. Better to get the authentication done in apex and using accesstoken do the callout from `Javascript` where these limits wont apply.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_api_calls_platform.htm) says callouts to external apis from `JS` is supported.

Comment: Right. I've retrieved files from external APIs of over 1GB using JavaScript, it's perfectly possible, even in Lightning.

Comment: @sfdcfox and Nagendra Singh. Thanks that helps. I am looking into calling the external endpoint from LWC. Are there any security concerns that I should be aware of. Meaning if the API call to external system is sending client id and secret, would be it be considered "safe" to make call from client side?

Comment: This is where you will have to tweak the authentication logic to send Auth Token instead of Client Id and Client Secret. As those will be exposed in the browser.

Comment: @NagendraSingh You mean to say that using apex code get the authentication token and then  use this authentication token in LWC to make the get request call?

Comment: @NagendraSingh Is there any reference if you can share the document with more details?

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you please share the document if you have that how to retrieve over 12 MB file by API from other system to salesforce?

Comment: @SandipPanchani You'll probably want to ask a separate question, because we'll need more information on what specifically you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sfdcfox I need exactly code reference what you did "I've retrieved files from external APIs of over 1GB using JavaScript, it's perfectly possible, even in Lightning" and said in first comment of this answer. Can you please share it if you have?

Comment: @SandipPanchani Please see fetch api in javascript for reference.